# print new line after each card suit

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to print out each suit in a different line:

this is how is coming out: `2C 3C 4C 5C 6C...2H 3H 4H...`

this is how I want it :

```
2C 3C 4C 5C 6C...
2H 3H 4H 5H 6H
```

here is part of my code :

```
public DeckOfCards()
{ 
      for (PlayingCard.CardRank rank : PlayingCard.CardRank.values())   
          for (PlayingCard.CardSuit suit : PlayingCard.CardSuit.values())
          {
              System.out.printf(" %c%c ", rank.getSymbol(),suit.getSymbol());
          }
```

I thought about writing an if statement( if rank is equals to ace since ace is the last char printing out) then `System. out.println()`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You thought about writing an if statement. Did you try it?

Comment: yeah but I am not using the right syntax inside the if statement and is throwing me an error

Comment: You literally just asked how to sort your deck in another post.

Comment: If you have tried a if but unable to get it right, (even after deciphering compilation errors and trying options), you can post *that* as a question. Rather than asking what to do.

Comment: @Eric he is not printing the cards in a specific deck.  He's just enumerating / printing all of the possible cards.

Comment: @StephenC OP has 3 questions in 15 mins and seems as though he's getting SO to do the work for him. That's what I was getting at.

Comment: @Eric: I'm seeing that pattern too...

Answer (score 4):

I will not give you a direct answer.

You are looping through the ranks, then the suits, and printing `RANK SUIT`.

After the suit you need a space. You already have that one.

After all the suits of the rank, you need a new line.

So you have to detect end of each rank (of all suits of the rank). That should be the end of all iterations of the particular rank, and just before the end of the iteration of the rank right? Where would it be?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print( rank.getSymbol());
System.out.print(suit.getSymbol());
System.out.println();
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The asker wants newlines after each suit is finished printing.